# I have 5 classes and navigate between them by drawer side

Tags: android, localization, flutter, globalization

I have 5 classes and navigate between them by drawer side     I want   when the language of the app is English   run  a specific  class   and other languages run another class
how can I do this  ?

Comment: you need to share your code or at least mention the plugin you are sing for localization

Comment: my dear  raouf     i can't put  the code  in the comment  it say too long

Comment: Just put it in the post you can edit it